# Process run time in Android

Tags: android, process

I'm trying to measure how fast from application start a certain operations are performed in my app. In order to do that I'm trying to use 2 methods:

- `Process.getElapsedCpuTime` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process#getElapsedCpuTime()
- `Process.getStartElapsedRealtime` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process#getStartElapsedRealtime()

As per my understanding getElapsedCpuTime returns number of milliseconds from application start and getStartElapsedRealtime returns time ,when application has been started. Because of this If I will substract `Process.getStartElapsedRealtime` from 'SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`I should get a similar value as one returned from`Process.getElapsedCpuTime`.

here is example implementation:

```
Long processStartTime = Process.getStartElapsedRealtime();
Long systemClock = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
long processTime = systemClock - processStartTime;


Long elapsedTime = Process.getElapsedCpuTime()

//processTime should have a similar value to elapsedTime
```

When I implemented above tho I noticed that `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - Process.getStartElapsedRealtime()` is different from `Process.getElapsedCpuTime()`. Some times difference is only 500 miliseconds but sometimes `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - Process.getStartElapsedRealtime()` is 2 times more than `Process.getElapsedCpuTime()`

Why there is a difference between those two time measures?